# Getting an error while installing pydictionary

Tags: python, pip, pydictionary

I was trying to install pydictionary.
I ran `pip install PyDictionary` and the following error appears:

```
Collecting PyDictionary
  Using cached PyDictionary-2.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (6.1 kB)
Collecting bs4 (from PyDictionary)
  Using cached bs4-0.0.1.tar.gz (1.1 kB)
  ERROR: Error [WinError 225] Operation did not complete successfully because the file contains a virus or potentially unwanted software while executing command python setup.py egg_info     
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 225] Operation did not complete successfully because the file contains a virus or potentially unwanted software
```

I tried to download pydictionary and facing an error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69186475/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/74741686/7976758 , https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&pws=0&q=pip+ERROR%3A+Error+WinError+225+Operation+did+not+complete+successfully+because+the+file+contains+a+virus+or+potentially+unwanted+software